# Android IntenService

Tags: android, service

Уважаемые, помогите разобраться, что значит Service и что значит IntentService, Я понимаю что IntentService это абстракция Service, и всё это как служба, но вот вопрос в чём, мне нужна служба которая в фоне с некоторым интервалом запускала какой либо функционал, то есть  допустим отправку каких то новых значений в базу данных. Наставьте на истину пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Service - это программа, которая может работать в фоне и не имеет GUI. Все. IntentService -  это частный случай Service. Он умеет получать intent'ы и обрабатывать их в фоне (под словом фон я не считаю, что она будет работать тихонько и никому не будет мешать. Она просто не будет иметь gui). Также этот сервис умеет выключаться, если нет intent'ов.

Подсистема андроида предоставляет для запуска периодических событий специальный интерфейс - AlarmManager. Почитать можно [здесь](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). Он позволяет выполнять разные функции с интервалом в один день или каждые три часа. При этом не важно, запущено Ваше приложение или нет. AlarmManager обычно посылает intent и Ваш IntentService получает его и обрабатывает.

Если событие нужно повторять достаточно часто и приложение при этом запущено (например, менять картинки раз в 3 секунды), то тут достаточно [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).postAtTime().

Comment: каждые 3-и часа, то есть?) То есть уже это максимум минимальный интервал, да нет же, ну хендлер объект для выполнения отложенных задач как я помню, вот только в сервисе не пробовал, видать столько подходов что и не понятно какой выбрать правильно, вот где бы из практики уже взглянуть на готовый проект с где сервис служба отправляет постоянно запрос на на сервер где хранятся входящие сообщения, как на клиентских приложений типа контакта

Comment: github+аналоги или [reverse engineering][1]


  [1]: http://boomik.ru/polnaya-dekompilyaciya-android-prilozhenij

Comment: Хотел бы поправить, что ни Service, ни  IntentService не имеют оба GUI. Только Service запускается в Main Thread, а IntentService изначально в отдельном потоке. Отсюда можно плясать дальше. С обычной службой (Service) можно связать через onBind и вернуть из неё данные в главный поток какого-нибудь Activity или Fragment'а, а из IntentService можно будет вернуть только через BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: ох, видимо @Алексей Навальный оправдывает свой ник.

Я не говорил о том, что handler должен использоваться внутри сервиса.

Что использовать - я уже написал. Если интервал обновлений большой (то есть больше 10-20 минут) - используйте AlarmManager, который будет слать intent, а отдельно intent сервис, который BroadcastReceiver будет их ловить и обрабатывать. Все.

Если же нужно обновления дергать постоянно (например каждую минуту), тогда обычный сервис с стандартным sleep (только делать все в дополнительном треде). 

Если нужно каждую секунду и пока жив gui - тогда handler.